# Some undesired words appeared in Google's snippets, how to get read of it?

Tags: seo

I know Google's creation of sites' titles and descriptions (or "snippets") are mainly come from META description. However, when one of my web pages shows up, there are some undesired words like price (which is not good at all). What I want it to show is just the description of the product rather than its price. Actually the price only mentioned twice in the whole page.

How could this happen? And how can I remedy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the price in the snippet is actually very desirable for most people. If your price is higher than the competition's for the same products they probably don't want to buy from you and check out other results instead.

To make sure the search engines don't see the price (and thus don't display it in the results) you should use JavaScript. I think even Amazon does this to prevent screen scraping in some cases. It should be easy, especially with something like jQuery.

```
$('#priceForProduct987A').html("$125")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to control the snippet displayed by google through the use of the meta tags:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812

However the results displayed by Google in this case might be different if someone is trying to do some searching on a product. Google will then think you're shopping for that product and try to display the price of it. This might be the case for you.